# Changing ownership of new volume

Tags: permissions, ownership

I have installed a second hard drive on my Ubuntu 14.04.  I made the mistake of naming the owner as "Me".  How can I change the ownership to my log on ID?

Answer (score 1):

If the disk is mounted on `/media/usb1/` you can do

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /media/usb1
```

the same command applies for SATA mounted disks as well, the disk would be mounted at `/media/<UUID>`. You can run `sudo blkid` to find the UUID of your partition and replace `<UUID>` with the actual UUID of your device.

and it will set ALL user and group permission to the user you are doing this with.

removed comment

Comment: Not USB. SATA on MB.

Comment: @TheodorePLundgren it is all the same; only the directory is different. Edit into your question the mount point of the disk and I'll change the answer.

Comment: ted@ted-desktop:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for ted: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="d522ab8f-f466-4de0-9608-2e4804f2fb2f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="6a023b35-821e-4ae4-815c-f478d2c9cea7" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="B2A4045BA4042507" TYPE="ntfs"

Comment: I formatted the drive to Ext4:

ted@ted-desktop:~$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null
/dev/sda1: UUID="d522ab8f-f466-4de0-9608-2e4804f2fb2f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="6a023b35-821e-4ae4-815c-f478d2c9cea7" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="NewDrive" UUID="d92b8ac6-e894-47dd-aff4-5c3095765ae0" TYPE="ext4"